# Enterprise Wiki Content Types vs Page Layouts

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, page-layout, wiki, enterprise-wiki

I am looking at using the Enterprise Wiki site in SharePoint Online to document a series of SQL Server databases.

I would like to create templates for each database object type so that the required information is captured when creating a wiki page, prompting the user what to input and each having their own layout.

In order to achieve this should I be looking at creating Content Types or Page Layouts or a combination of both? Any suggested articles on how to perform this task? I am struggling to find guidance on how to make the most of the Enterprise Wiki.